# How to get name and logo to repeat for every page of a table (tablix)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I'm trying to recreate a report created from Crystal Reports to SSRS.

The report has the company name  and logo on top, a chart below and a table that can span multiple pages. If the table for a company takes more than one page to display, the comapny name and logo is displayed for every page.

I was somehow able to do this, except for the repeating name and logo.

[image: Current]

I need it to look like this:

[image: Desired]

Comment: why not just add it to your report Header? It should repeat for all pages.. simply right click on the design window.. add page header.. now you can add images and what not to the header section.

Comment: Hi @Harry I can't add it to a header because the there are multiple companies in the report. So, I need to use tablix and add a page break for each company ID. Is there a way that I can add the company name to the header without needing to use tablix?

Comment: Ah I see. Have you tried adding the company info and logo your Group header line and then make sure it repeats on new page? Looks like you already have a page break in between the company groups..

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but I already tried to create a table and placed another table inside the header that would store the Company Names and on the detail part of the main table I added the chart and the table that spans multiple pages. When I do this, the page break doesn't work and all of the company names are just listed at the top.

Comment: Please see my answer below.. depending on how you are sourcing your company logs and details.. you can use a switch statement to choose the right details or use a lookup command if the details are coming from another dataset

Answer (score 1):

Add you company and logo information in the top line but INSIDE the group (assuming company is the grouping here). Then click on the little down arrow to the right of the "Column Groups" window (bottom right) and select Advanced Mode

It should show up some Static elements under the  Row Groups windows.

Select one at a time and then click on the properties window.. then select RepeatonNewPage = True

Do this for all the static group above the detailed group. You many need to set the KeepwithGroup property as well..

Now if the group goes over a page.. it should repeat the top section of your report for that company

Comment: This somehow didn't work for me. I'm not sure if I did anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked around my issue. Added a row, placed the company name on that row and hid the entire row. In my header I added a textbox and used the expression ReportItems!CompanyName.Value.